# scope of a variable in case of external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically i am using some other websites javascripts to get a good looking layout but i have added this functionality in which i get a value from a text box like this

```
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.nanoscroller/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.resize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery-flot/plugins/jquery.flot.orderBars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery-flot/plugins/curvedLines.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-us-merc-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-uk-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-fr-merc-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-us-il-chicago-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-au-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-in-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-ca-lcc-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/countup/countUp.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/lib/chartjs/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app-dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    function execute()
    {
        var Search = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
        App.init();
        App.dashboard();

    }
```

these App.init();
are some external scripts that initialises a var variable which has very custom features.like charts,graphs etc
The value stored in Search can i use it in those javascripts that initialises App. Will the scope of variable exist in such case ?. if not how can i do so and use this Search variable value in all the referenced javascripts

Comment: Personally i'd either do the lookup for that id in those App functions wherever it is needed.  But if you want to decouple them more, I'd create a namespace that contains it and then let those others reference the value in that global namespace.

Comment: @Taplar so i should do    var Search = document.getElementById('searchbox').value; in the external scripts  to get the value ?

Comment: Sure, if it is in the DOM any script can find any element. Btw, you got jquery all over your imports so why not use $('#searchbox') ? ;)